# Key-mon on KXStudio (ubuntu14.04, KDE 4.13.3) doesn't launch

Tags: 14.04, kde4

I had downloaded and installed the key-mon program from here: https://code.google.com/archive/p/key-mon/downloads

But it doesn't launch. I tried a few older versions - the same result.

How can I fix it?

I launched the file `key-mon` (in `/usr/bin`) through the terminal and got this report:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/key-mon", line 3, in <module>
    km.main()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/keymon/key_mon.py", line 1032, in main
    keymon = KeyMon(opts)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/keymon/key_mon.py", line 130, in __init__
    self.devices = xlib.XEvents()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/keymon/xlib.py", line 80, in __init__
    self.record_display = display.Display()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Xlib/display.py", line 80, in __init__
    self.display = _BaseDisplay(display)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Xlib/display.py", line 62, in __init__
    display.Display.__init__(*(self, ) + args, **keys)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Xlib/protocol/display.py", line 61, in __init__
    name, host, displayno)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Xlib/support/connect.py", line 93, in get_auth
    return getattr(mod, modname).get_auth(sock, dname, host, dno)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Xlib/support/unix_connect.py", line 116, in new_get_auth
    au = xauth.Xauthority()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Xlib/xauth.py", line 84, in __init__
    self.entries.append((family, addr.decode('UTF-8'),
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/encodings/utf_8.py", line 16, in decode
    return codecs.utf_8_decode(input, errors, True)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xc0 in position 0: invalid start byte
```

Exactly:  I had launched (double clicking) the file 'keymon_1.17-1_all.deb' after downloading. This opened the 'GDebi' Package Installer:

```
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3wLXUcKN8LAMWQtbkRhNUtHaE0/view
```

I had chose 'Download package' option at the bottom. After that I got:

```
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3wLXUcKN8LAWEg4d05zaE5DMms/view
```

I had pressed 'Install Package' at the bottom of the window. And got this:

```
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3wLXUcKN8LAbEpnRGdka1F5dzg/view
```

After, I found Key Mon in my Launcher Menu and clicked on it:

```
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3wLXUcKN8LAWFNDMVV3a3FxM2c/view
```

and the Key Mon launcher appeared in the Task Manager:

```
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3wLXUcKN8LAdUVZeFdKN3p4bHM/view
```

But actually the program was not running. Just only the launcher in the Task Manager was shown about 30 seconds and disappeared.
 The reason why I didn't use 'Ubuntu Trusty's repo' is just I didn't know about this when I found Key Mon as a 'screen show' program in google. But anyway, later, I removed Key Mon through the terminal 'sudo apt-get purge remove key-mon' . And had installed again through: 'sudo apt-get install key-mon' . The result was the same - Key Mon doesn't launch.

Comment: How *exactly* did you install key-mon? Were there any warning or error messages during the installation? Is there a reason why you didn't install the version [included in Ubuntu Trusty's package repository](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/key-mon)? You can install the latter via `sudo apt-get install --reinstall key-mon`.

Comment: @David Foerster : So I did as you suggested 'sudo apt-get install --reinstall key-mon' there was no any error or warning messages in terminal during installation. But the same - Key Mon doesn't launch. If I run the key-mon through the terminal - in gives me the same report as I wrote in my post. (I'm not so skilled in Linux, sorry if I write so much in comments)

Comment: I want to address to Stack Exchange: I didn't find a vertical spoiler for my terminal messages. Is there any formatting for this?

Comment: Please [edit] your question when you want to add information or clarify something. Questions also allow you to format code listings suitably with the `{}`button in the editor toolbar.

Comment: @David Foerster: Thanks! I got some problem with editing the question: I tried to cut my comments and put them in to question, but when I pressed 'Save Edits' at the bottom - the red notification switched on 
×
'You need at least 10 reputation to post more than 2 links.'   So I canceled editing and leaved my comments at the place.

Comment: You can format the additional URLs as code which the spam filter disregards and hopefully a more reputed user (e. g. me) can fix the formatting for you. Thanks for the detailed description by the way!